# route to different component for similar routes with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I´m trying to route to different components but for the last route is catching it

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/users" exact strict component={Users}/> // this one works fine
    <Route path="/users/new" exact strict component={NewUser}/> // this one is not. the next route is catching it...
    <Route path="/users/:userId" exact strict component={UserDetails}/>
</Switch>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: You just remove exact and strict

Comment: I tried that @SanatGupta but is showing both components at the same time :(

Comment: @handsome there is lot of working answer here, you may try them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you rearrange your Routes it will work, here is my idea

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/users/new" component={NewUser}/>
    <Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserDetails}/>
    <Route path="/users" component={Users}/> // this one works fine
</Switch>
```

It works for me

You can try this, hopefully it will works

Comment: this worked for me. I have nested <Switch> now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi this my basic route it's working fine for me have a look.

Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import login from "./login";
import Home from "./Home";
import GoogleApi from "./GoogleApi";
import State from "./State";
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={login} />
            <Route path="/googleapi" component={GoogleApi} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/state" component={State} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: all your routes have different names. in My case I have /users/new and /users/123

Comment: But your component is different right see it's working fine for same as your route  `<BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/users" exact strict component={Home} />
            <Route path="/users/new" exact strict component={GoogleApi} />
            <Route path="/users/:userId" exact strict component={State} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>`

Comment: Please serve your application again

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your routes it works fine.i have test it in my project

```
    <Route path="/users/new" exact  component={NewUser}/> 
    <Route path="/users/:userId" exact  component={UserDetails}/>
    <Route path="/users" exact  component={Users}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
            <Route path="/users/new" component={NewUser} />
            <Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserDetails} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```